# HTMLのボタンのエラー

Tags: python, html, css, django

[DjangoGirlsというチュートリアル](https://djangogirlsjapan.gitbooks.io/workshop_tutorialjp/content/django_forms/)に従って、PythonのDjangoを使いblogを作成しようとしています。そこで、ブログの投稿ページは作成し、データをデータベースに保存することはできたものの、次の画面に遷移することができずエラーが出てしまいました。

### 発生している問題・エラーメッセージ

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

### ソースコード

post_edit.html

```
{% extends 'posts/base.html' %}
{% block content %}
    <h1>New post</h1>
    <form method="POST" class="post-form">{% csrf_token %}
        {{ form.as_p }}
        <button type="submit" class="save btn btn-default">Save</button>
    </form>
{% endblock %}
```

views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render, get_object_or_404, redirect
from django.utils import timezone
from .models import Post
from .forms import PostForm


# Create your views here.
def post_list(request):
        posts = Post.objects.filter(published_date__lte=timezone.now()).order_by('published_date')
        return render(request, 'posts/post_list.html', {'posts': posts})

def post_detail(request, pk):
        post = get_object_or_404(Post, pk=pk)
        return render(request, 'posts/post_detail.html', {'post': post})

def post_new(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = PostForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            post = form.save(commit=False)
            post.author = request.user
            post.save()
            return redirect('posts.views.post_detail', pk=post.pk)
    else:
        form = PostForm()
    return render(request, 'posts/post_edit.html', {'form': form})

def post_edit(request, pk):
    post = get_object_or_404(Post, pk=pk)
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = PostForm(request.POST, instance=post)
        if form.is_valid():
            post = form.save(commit=False)
            post.author = request.user
            post.save()
            return redirect('posts.views.post_detail', pk=post.pk)
    else:
        form = PostForm(instance=post)
    return render(request, 'posts/post_edit.html', {'form': form})
```

base.html
    {% load staticfiles %}

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Blog</title>
        <link href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lobster&subset=latin,latin-ext" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="page-header">
            <h1><a href="/">Blog</a></h1>
            <input type="button" value="投稿" onClick="location.href='/post/new';">
        </div>

        <div class="content container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-8">
                {% block content %}
                {% endblock %}
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

`

Comment: スタック・オーバーフローへようこそ！　コードを整形してくださりありがとうございます。できればググラビリティのために、エラーメッセージを画像でなく文章にしたり（「ブロック引用」機能が有用です）、タイトルをより具体的なものにしたりしていただくとより良い形になるかと思います。よろしくお願いします。

Comment: マルチポスト　https://teratail.com/questions/65075

Answer (score 1):

エラー画面を確認するとRequest URLが`http://127.0.0.1/post/5/edit/posts.views.post_detail`となっています。
おそらく`redirect('posts.views.post_detail', pk=post.pk)`のviewの指定が間違っており、`'posts.views.post_detail'`という文字列がそのままURLに使用されているものと推測されます。
`'posts.views.post_detail'`を存在するviewに変更する必要があるのですが、URLから推測するに`'post.views.post_detail'`ではないでしょうか。

`redirect`の仕様に関しては下記を参照してください。
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/http/shortcuts/#redirect